# Stroustrup's C++ Book Challenge, Can someone help me understand this code?

Tags: c++

I saw this code from the Stroustrup's book, but I can't understand how it works.
I just can't get how it increases by " 0, 1, 4, 9..."

```
int archaic_square(int v) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i) {
        total += v;
    }
    return total;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        cout << i << '\t' << archaic_square(i) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A multiplication is done by successive adds. Basiclly it is what the program is doing. For example, if i = 3, total will be 3 + 3 + 3

Comment: ```for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i){
    total += v;
}``` like ```total = v*v;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `archaic_square` is starting `total` off as zero, then adding `v` to it `v` times (in the loop).

By definition, it will then end up as:

```
0 + v + v + … + v
    \___________/
       v times
```

which is `0 + v * v`, or `v2`.

In more explicit detail:

- adding zero to zero, zero times, gives you zero (0);
- adding one to zero, once, gives you one (0, 1);
- adding two to zero, two times, gives you four (0, 2, 4);
- adding three to zero, three times, gives you nine (0, 3, 6, 9);
- adding four to zero, four times, gives you sixteen (0, 4, 8, 12, 16);
- and so on, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

Remember from arithmetic that multiplication is repeated just a addition (or rather a repeated addition by definition)? That's all that's happening here.

Since `v` is getting added `v` times, it is the same as `v * v`, or `v` squared.

Answer (score 0):

That code calculates squares by the method of differences. It's an alternative way of evaluating functions, and has some benefits over the usual plug-in-the-values approach. It was used in Babbage's [difference engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine), which was designed in the early 1800s to calculate mathematical tables for logarithms, trig functions, etc. to 40 (!) digits.

The underlying idea is that you begin with a list of values that you know how to evaluate. You subtract each value from its neighboring value, giving you a list of first differences. Then you subtract each difference value from its neighboring difference value, giving you a list of second differences. Continue until you reach a level where all the difference values are equal. For a second-order polynomial (such as x^2) the second differences will all be equal. For a third-order polynomial, the third differences will all be equal. And so on.

So for calculating squares, you end up with this:

```
Value    First Difference    Second Difference
  0
  1            1
  4            3                   2
  9            5                   2
 16            7                   2
 25            9                   2
```

Now you can reverse the process. Start with a result of 0. Add the first difference (1), giving the next result (1). Then increase the first difference by the second difference (2), giving the next first difference (3); add that to the previous result (1), giving the next result (4). Then increase the new first difference (3) by the second difference (2), giving the next first difference (5); add that to the previous result (4), giving the next result (9). Continue until done.

So with only the first value (0), the first difference (1), and the (constant) second difference (2), we can generate as long a list of squares as we would like.

When you need a **list** of results, calculating them one after another like this replaces multiplication with addition, which, back in the olden days, was much faster. Further, if a computer (back when a computer was a person who did tedious calculations to produce mathematical) made a mistake, all the results after that mistake would be wrong, too, so the mathematician in charge of the project didn't have to provide for checking every result; spot checking was sufficient.

Calculating trig functions, of course, is a bit more tricky, because they aren't defined by polynomials. But over a small enough region they can be approximated by a polynomial.

Babbage's engine would have calculated 40 digit values, with up to 7 levels of differences. It mechanically went through the sequence of steps I mentioned above, grinding out results at a rate of one every few seconds. Babbage didn't actually build the full difference engine; he got an inspiration for a much more powerful "Analytical engine" which he also never built. It would have been a precursor to modern digital computers, with 1000 40-digit storage units, an arithmetic processor, and punched cards to control the sequence of operations.